# jQuery unbind , bind function not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

Can anyone help me to differentiate this two line , one is working fine on IE as well as FF, but second is working fine only in FF .

```
$(window).resize( function() ); // Works in both IE and FF

$(window).unbind('resize').bind('resize', function() ); // Works only in FF
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its simple code : 
  $(window).resize( function()
  { 
    if (panels.resize_timer) clearTimeout(panels.resize_timer);
    panels.resize_timer = setTimeout("panels_resize();", 500);
  });

And I am sure , not any issue due to this code .

Comment: After loading the window first time , the resizing function is calling properly on IE8 and FF, but after resize the window this function is not calling in IE8 .

Comment: odd - try compare your code against this working example: http://jsbin.com/akoho5/5

Comment: I having the same issue with window unbind. I updated jQuery from 1.5.1 to 1.5.2 but that didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

Try other objects. For example, $(document) or $('body').

If handling resizing is important, i usually create wrapping div and check its width and height on timeout.